# How to transfer a file using a proxy with JSch library

Tags: java, sftp, file-transfer, jsch, http-proxy

I want to transfer files to a remote location and I am bound to use a proxy server for that. I was able to connect to the FTP location via following command :

```
sftp -o "ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x <proxy_host>:<proxy_port> %h %p" username@ftp_server:
```

But I want to automate this process of file transfer and I am using JSch for SFTP and snippet of code is below:

```
String sourceFile = sourceDir + fileName;
JSch jsch = new JSch();
int port = Integer.parseInt(getFtpPort());
Session session = jsch.getSession(getUserName(), getHost(), port);
session.setConfig(STRICT_HOST_CHECKING, ANSWER);
session.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP(<proxy_host>, <proxy_port>));
session.setPassword(getPassword());
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel(FILE_PROTOCOL);
channel.connect();
sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
sftpChannel.cd(desDir);
File fileToTransfer =  new File(sourceFile);
sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(fileToTransfer), fileName);
```

With above code I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ProxyHTTP.connect(ProxyHTTP.java:158)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:210)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Facing the same issue using HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
Session session = jsch.getSession(RemoteUserName, RemoteIpAddr, RemotePortNo);
session.setPassword(RemotePassword);
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP(ProxyName, ProxyPort));
session.connect();
```

Comment: `session.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP(proxyName, proxyPort));`
this worked fow me. thank you

Answer (score 6):

This Worked for me

```
ProxyHTTP  proxy = new ProxyHTTP("192.168.10.1",80)
proxy.setUserPasswd("username","password");
session.setProxy(proxy);
```

Answer (score 1):

use 
    session.setProxy(new ProxySOCKS5(, ));

Instead of `proxyHTTP`, 
hope it works for you...
it worked for me